# How to we write a recursive function call in python

Tags: python-3.x, function, recursion

I have a function "lengthOfLongestSubstring" as in the below code and need to recursively call the function with substring of "s"(For example s[3:])
How do I call it?

I have tried calling recursively like this:
lengthOfLongestSubstring(s[1:])

But its popping up an error that "NameError: name 'lengthOfLongestSubstring' is not defined"

```
    class Solution:
        def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s: 'str') -> 'int':
            count = 0
            list1 = []
            for i in range(len(s)):            
                if s[i] not in list1:
                    list1.append(s[i])
                    count= count+1
                    print (list1)
                else:
                    substr = s[i:]
                    if (count < lengthOfLongestSubstring(substr)):
                       count = lengthOfLongestSubstring(substr)
                    break
            return (count)
```

Expected the recursive call of the function but getting the below mentioned error:

```
NameError: name 'lengthOfLongestSubstring' is not defined
Line 15 in lengthOfLongestSubstring (Solution.py)
Line 29 in __helper__ (Solution.py)
Line 60 in _driver (Solution.py)
Line 73 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

Comment: Have given the code in Question. Could you refer that.

Comment: Well, how do you call methods of a class inside a method of said class? This problem doesn't have anything to do with recursion at this point

Comment: remove the class definition and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Your `lengthOfLongestSubstring` is a *method* inside a class, so you have to call it like this:

```
self.lengthOfLongestSubstring(substr)
```

I don't really see the need to define it inside a class, I'd rather extract the whole thing out of it, and then you can invoke it normally. Just delete the line with `class Solution` on it and indent everything one tab to the left.